# Typo3 tx_news TagList Filter based on selecting two different Category Menu on Same Page?

Tags: typo3, tx-news

Hi all I am having an Issue Lets Suppose I am having a news Tag record and news record with two different Category Menu as describe below
In List View i selected C1 (show all Videos with Selected Category OR)

V1(Vedio)-C1(Category)-T1(Tag), V2-C1-T2, V3-C1-T1, V4-C1,T2  in same way V5-C2-T1, V6-C2-T2, V7-C2-T1, V8-C2-T2.Issue is when i choose C1 menu then T1 OR T2 Its fine..Showing V1,V3 or V2,V4...but when i choose C2 menu then T1 or T2 ,its giving the same Content V1,V3 or V2,V4.
for correct logic filter it should give..V5,V7 orV6,V8..becuase I selected C2 menu.
I am having two files which i think I have to correct but i don't know how to do this?

1.C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\typo3conf\ext\news\Resources\Private\Templates\Styles\Twb\Templates\Category\List.html

```html
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<f:layout name="General" />
<!--
 =====================
  Templates/Category/List.html
-->

<f:section name="content">
 <f:if condition="{categories}">
  <f:then>
   <f:render section="categoryTree" arguments="{categories:categories,overwriteDemand:overwriteDemand,class:'nav nav-sidebar category-menu-view'}" />
  </f:then>
  <f:else>
   <f:translate key="list_nocategoriesfound" />
  </f:else>
 </f:if>
</f:section>

<f:section name="categoryTree">

 <ul class="{class}">
  <f:for each="{categories}" as="category">
   <li>
    <f:if condition="{category.item.uid} == {overwriteDemand.categories}">
     <f:then>
      <f:link.page title="{category.item.title}" class="active" pageUid="{settings.listPid}"
       additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{categories: category.item.uid}}}">{category.item.title}
      </f:link.page>
     </f:then>
     <f:else>
      <f:link.page title="{category.item.title}" pageUid="{settings.listPid}"
       additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{categories: category.item.uid}}}">{category.item.title}
      </f:link.page>
     </f:else>
    </f:if>

    <f:if condition="{category.children}">
     <f:render section="categoryTree" arguments="{categories: category.children,overwriteDemand:overwriteDemand,class:''}" />
    </f:if>
   </li>
  </f:for>
 </ul>
</f:section>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fFbX.jpg)2.C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\typo3conf\ext\news\Resources\Private\Templates\Styles\Twb\Templates\Tag\List.html

```html
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<f:layout name="General" />

<!--
 =====================
  Templates/Tag/List.html
-->

<f:section name="content">
 <f:if condition="{tags}">
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar tag-menu-view">
   <f:for each="{tags}" as="tag">
    <li class="{f:if(condition:'{tag.uid} == {overwriteDemand.tags}',then:'active',else:'')}">
     <f:link.page title="{tag.title}" pageUid="{settings.listPid}" additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{tags: tag}}}">
      {tag.title}
     </f:link.page>
    </li>
   </f:for>
  </ul>
 </f:if>
</f:section>
</html>
```

Comment: V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8 are the news Record, C1 and C2 are Category Menu and T1 and T2 are News Tag

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but I don't really understand what you want to achieve. However it seems that the best solution would be to write a custom extension which generates the views you need, based on EXT:news. This is described in the manual here https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/drafts/github/georgringer/news/DeveloperManual/ExtendNews/ExtensionBasedOnNews/Index.html